# CSS: Why isnt "margin-left" working and "width"?

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I have a div inside another div.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eT7U9/263/

```
.primaryMenu .Wrap {
    border:thin solid black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I want the inner div to shift a bit towards right side and for that I provided "margin-left: 100px;" But this didnt work. Can someone please tell me why? And whats the correct way to do it?

Another question: 
When I give 50% width(or any width, in fact) to the inner div, it acquires the centre position of the parent Div. Why is it so? Shouldn't it just stay there at top left with width 50%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup negates the margin with an inline style.

```
  <div class="Wrap" style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

Inline styles will take precedence over a CSS class.  Remove the inline style from the `div`.

```
  <div class="Wrap">
```

This should also fix the 50% issue you cite, since it was specifying `auto` for the left and right margins in the inline style.

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/eT7U9/265/

Comment: It also answers your second question about the top left, the auto margin centers elements.

Comment: Oh, I knew that but just didnt check it. Thanks for your help. :) DAMN! My mistake!

Comment: @KevinBowersox I have another doubt. I dont want to use it the border property of the inner div. Now, when I erase that property, I whole thing shifts down in mozilla firefox. Its working fine in jsFiddle. Can you tell me why is it happening so?

Comment: @NavneetSaini You should have to mark this as resolved. As Kevin specify what the problem is.